# Analog of "select level from dual connect by level < 10" for Sybase?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sybase

By **select level from dual connect by level < 10** in Oracle I can generate sub-query of integer and transform it to another sequence.

Is this possible with Sybase?

**PS** I want to find dates where are no data in table (missing days). In Oracle I do this as:

```
select to_date('2012-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')+level-1 from dual
    connect by level < to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - to_date('2012-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  MINUS
select distinct date from TBL
    where date between to_date('2012-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                   and to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

In Sybase analog for **MINUS** is:

```
select whatever from table1 T1
  where not exists
  ( select 1 from table2 where id = T1.id )
```

but I don't know analog for **connect by level**...

**UPDATE** Is there any way to create temporary table in Sybase without actually storing data to disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oracle syntax you use is a hierarchical query used as a row generator. Sybase has the [sa_rowgenerator](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/sa-rowgenerator-sysproc.html) system procedure can be used to generate a set of integers between a start and end value.

The following will produce a column of integers between 1 and 255.

```
SELECT row_num FROM sa_rowgenerator( 1, 255 );
```

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1270/html/iqref/iqref771.htm - official docs for **sa_rowgenerator**

Answer (score 1):

sa_rowgenerator system procedure required DBA authority . Users without DBA authority must be granted EXECUTE permission to run the stored procedure.