# SQL query to find previous quarter end date for range of dates

Tags: sybase

I have two input dates as parameters and my query should return previous quarter end dates between two dates.
We have four quarters in a year.

```
 Q1 -Jan to March
 Q2-Apr to June
 Q3-Jul to Sep
 Q4-Oct to Dec
```

> Input Dates  Q1-2015 , Q2-2016

Number of Dates to be returned from query

```
 Dec 31st 2014
 March 31st 2015
 June 30 2015
 Sep 30 2015
 Dec 31st 2015
 March 31st 2016
```

> Input Dates 
>       Q1-2016 Q2-2016

```
Number of Dates to be returned from query
 Dec 31st 2015
 March 31 2016
```

I need it to be returned in a query.
 Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include some sample data from your table to go along with your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below takes the inputs as bind variables. It works ONLY if the inputs are exactly in that format (a seven-character string `'Qx-yyyy'` where `x` is from 1 to 4 and `yyyy` is a valid year) and ONLY if the "to-quarter" is equal to or later than the "from-quarter"; my solution does not do any validation to ensure this is the case, and the behavior if these rules are violated is undefined (which means I didn't spend time to test any "rule-breaking" cases).

```
with
     prep ( from_qtr, from_yr, to_qtr, to_yr ) as (
       select to_number(substr(:from_year, 2, 1)),
              to_number(substr(:from_year, 4   )),
              to_number(substr(:to_year  , 2, 1)),
              to_number(substr(:to_year  , 4   ))
       from   dual
     )
select add_months( to_date(to_char(from_yr) || '/' || to_char(3 * from_qtr - 2) 
                                 || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') - 1,  
                   3 * (level - 1)
                 )   as qtr_end_date
from   prep
connect by level <= 1 + 4 * (to_yr - from_yr) + (to_qtr - from_qtr)
order by qtr_end_date
;
```

NOTE:  If you can't use connect-by-level, you can do without it, but you will need a mechanism to generate numbers from 1 to a sufficiently high limit. You can either hard-code a `num` table (similar to the one below) or use some mechanism to read row numbers from a table with many rows. Here is a possible solution:

```
with
     prep ( from_qtr, from_yr, to_qtr, to_yr ) as (
       select to_number(substr(:from_year, 2, 1)),
              to_number(substr(:from_year, 4   )),
              to_number(substr(:to_year  , 2, 1)),
              to_number(substr(:to_year  , 4   ))
       from   dual
     ),
     num ( rn ) as (select rownum from all_tab_columns)
select add_months( to_date(to_char(from_yr) || '/' || to_char(3 * from_qtr - 2) 
                                 || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') - 1,  
                   3 * (rn - 1)
                 )   as qtr_end_date
from   prep cross join num
where rn <= 1 + 4 * (to_yr - from_yr) + (to_qtr - from_qtr)
order by qtr_end_date
;
```

The hardcoded alternative is to say `num ( rn ) as select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual union all select 3 from dual ......   )` and you will need to have sufficient numbers to cover all your possible cases.

Comment: Hi,this is what exactly needed,I am looking in sybase.do we have connect by in Sybase.

Comment: I only speak Oracle. If you use Sybase, why is your post tagged "oracle"?

Comment: Hi,did not find tag for sybase,so thought I can write in sybase if I get in oracle,can we modify this without using connect by,but output of this query is correct,I checked in oracle.Same logic without connect by can we acheive

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this

Comment: I warmly recommend Google. Here is what I found when I googled "Sybase connect by level": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624620/analog-of-select-level-from-dual-connect-by-level-10-for-sybase - it was the first match returned by Google. It seems to explain how to do the analog of connect-by-level in Sybase. What it means I have no idea.

Comment: I also edited your post and changed the tag to Sybase - I just started typing and the web page offered me the Sybase tag choices.

Comment: yeah I saw it,not much info,can you change the query without using connect by?

Comment: You use Sybase. I use Oracle. I didn't know what Sybase is until a few minutes ago, I had to Google it to see what it means. No, I don't think I can change it... I don't know the first thing about Sybase, and I can't test what I write (and I never post solutions without testing). Good luck!

Comment: Hi,no in oracle only I am asking can you rewrite your query without connect by

Comment: I see. I can re-write it without using connect-by-level, but one way or another I need to generate row numbers. Not sure if the other methods would work in Sybase. I will add an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is what exactly needed,I am looking in sybase.do we have connect by in Sybase.